# C# ограничение обобщенных классов

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

```
class JustClass<T> where T:new()
{
    public T exm = new T();
    public JustClass()
    {

    }
    public T[] arr = new T [5];
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {


       JustClass<int> just = new JustClass<int>();

       just.Method();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

почему нельзя вместо *int* поставить *string* в *JustClass*

Answer (score 6):

Запускаем ваш проект на компиляцию, читаем сообщение об ошибке:

> Тип "string" для использования в качестве параметра "T" в универсальном типе или методе "JustClass" должен быть неабстрактным и иметь открытый конструктор без параметров

А у типа `string` нету конструктора без параметров. Ограничение на конструктор наложили вы сами, при помощи `where T : new()`. (Без него, понятно, `public T exm = new T();` не откомпилируется.)